# How to keep variable content over multiple requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to build a log file in memory using a `StringBuilder`, so I have a

```
private StringBuilder logFile = new StringBuilder();
```

in my controller class. Later than I append log lines to that object.

But after each request it is cleared. How do I keep the contents during multiple requests/views? What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a static field (make sure to properly synchronize access to it) or directly append the values to a file. Or simply use a logging framework which is designed exactly for that purpose. You don't need to be using 3rd party, .NET already has an excellent logging facilities built-in (look at the [`System.Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t15zda.aspx) namespace).

Comment: what do you mean by "properly synchronize access"?

Comment: You know, standard synchronization techniques, `lock` and stuff, things you do when you need to ensure that a single thread is accessing a shared resource.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. Instead of using a private field in the controller class I simply created a new static class with the static field and its contents are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Session` or `Cache` for storing data between requests, eg:

```
Session["data"] = logFile;
```

and then retrieve it:

```
logFile = Session["data"] as StringBuilder;
```

Comment: Thanks, but while it certainly works I wanted to avoid it as I read that it is bad design to use Session variables for that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [log4Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial) for any logging needs, works like a cham and does exactly what you are looking for.